# Function taking string array as parameter returning typed map to with same array keys

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have a function which takes an array of strings and returns a map with each element of the array as key. I would like the returned type to reflect that.

This is what I have now ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQCcCmBzBBnOTdAHgBVVMAPQqAEz1QPQSmwD4AKKAQwFtMAXIzjNWAGgoA3TFDh4hWbrRQAbAJ6pSAbQC6ASiEBvVFoDKqFpp1CmLbKgC+qQ6FSoYKAhlQBeKTLkAOixaCBhMDg4ABwlMFT1fNmdXN1QorTidX1QAAwASQx5+BwECuIccgG4Utyw4CHQ0KOqQNwcJQyduBmMzCzRSa2FRewc9FtrMesaMFodQUA8oLw8VJHQGPy0AIgAjFQhMbYlt7CwZY9RtkMvttTi1gHdtrO73TzgWpa9KbKxcAhEYhwNRRTBIMDvNYbLRQCC8XZEHScADkYCQSBRElW6zw40WniQKkwgTW2A4lEC+0OEko+JAoCAA)):

```
function register<T extends string>(name: string, events: readonly T[]): { [S in T]: string } {
  const r = events.reduce((p, el) => {
    p[el] = `${name}:${el}`;
    return p;
  }, {} as { [S in T]: string });
  return r;
}

const colors = ["blue", "green", "red", "yellow"] as const;
const x = register<typeof colors[number]>('foo', colors)
console.log(x.blue, x)
```

[image: showing type]

Is there a way to do this in one step?

```
const x = register<...?...>('foo', ["blue", "green", "red", "yellow"])
```

Comment: You can use template literal types: https://tsplay.dev/NllglN If it works for you, I could write up an answer explaining what I did, but it's past my bedtime so it'll probably be 8-10 hours before I respond.

Answer (score 0):

That is embarrassing :) I just tried to at least update my code with the two-step method and it looks like if I leave out the generic declaration, Typescript is smart enough to figure out the rest:

[image]